# Printing a node's value only if information exists

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking to print out a customer's options only if they have a value in the node. I can access the information and print it out, however, because of the while loop it prints out the information under each account. Any help or hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code to access the xml:

```
XPathNodeIterator ItemOptionsIter;
String ItemsearchStringOptions = "Order/Items/Item/CustomerOptions";
ItemOptionsIter = nav.Select(ItemsearchStringOptions);

if (ItemIter.Current.SelectSingleNode("CustomerOptions") != null)
{
    while (ItemOptionsIter.MoveNext())
    {
        XPathNodeIterator ItemOptions = ItemOptionsIter.Current.SelectChildren(XPathNodeType.Element);
        if (ItemOptions.Current.HasChildren)
        {
            txtItemInfo.Text = txtItemInfo.Text + "Size: " + ItemOptions.Current.SelectSingleNode("Size") + Environment.NewLine;
            txtItemInfo.Text = txtItemInfo.Text + "Color: " + ItemOptions.Current.SelectSingleNode("Color") + Environment.NewLine;
            txtItemInfo.Text = txtItemInfo.Text + "-------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<Item>
    <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
    <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
    <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost>
    <CustomerOptions>
        <Size>M</Size>
        <Color>Green</Color>
    </CustomerOptions>
</Item>
<Item>
    <PartNo>JETSSWEATER</PartNo>
    <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
    <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice>
    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
    <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost>
    <CustomerOptions>
        <Size>S</Size>
        <Color>White</Color>
    </CustomerOptions>
</Item>
<Item>
    <PartNo>JETSFLAG</PartNo>
    <Description>N.Y. Jets Flag for display</Description>
    <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost>
    <CustomerOptions/>
</Item>
```

And finally here is a sample of my output:

```
Part Number: JETSWEATER
Description: N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt
UnitPrice: 10.50
Quantity: 2
TotalCost: 21.00
-------------------------------------------------
Size: M
Color: Green
-------------------------------------------------
Size: S
Color: White
-------------------------------------------------
Part Number: JETSSWEATER
Description: N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt
UnitPrice: 7.50
Quantity: 3
TotalCost: 22.50
-------------------------------------------------
Size: M
Color: Green
-------------------------------------------------
Size: S
Color: White
-------------------------------------------------
Part Number: JETSFLAG
Description: N.Y. Jets Flag for display
UnitPrice: 5.00
Quantity: 1
TotalCost: 5.00
-------------------------------------------------
Size: M
Color: Green
-------------------------------------------------
Size: S
Color: White
-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: try changing your XPath expression to `Order/Items/Item/CustomerOptions[boolean(*)]`

Comment: @nate00234 Did the above work for you, or are you still hampered?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say construct your main loop to iterate through the Item nodes and print out their values, and then in the place where you would print out the options, do this:

```
XPathNodeIterator options = item.SelectNodes("CustomerOptions/*[. != '']");
if(options.Count != 0)
{
  XPathNavigator size = item.SelectSingleNode("CustomerOptions/Size[. != '']");
  if(size != null)
  {
    txtItemInfo.Text = txtItemInfo.Text + "Size: " + size.Value + Environment.NewLine;            
  }
  // Then do the same for color

  txtItemInfo.Text = txtItemInfo.Text + "-------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
}
```